# kendo ui grid looses selection when bound value changes

Tags: kendo-ui

It seems like the grid widget looses selection when a value that a column is bound to is changed. Does anyone know how to not loose the selection?
Example here (select a row then click "click here"):
http://jsbin.com/oyuher/1/edit

Comment: This was also helpful http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/QBESY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Grid is refreshed and any selection is lost. In [this code](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/preserve-grid-state-in-a-cookie.aspx) library you can get the idea how to persist the selection.

Basically there is a cookie which is used but since you do not reload the page you can simply safe it into a JavaScript variable.