# do not refresh the kendo grid on click of column header

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have kendo grid. when i sorting the columns the selected row is go off(deselect).
i need the selected row should not deselect on click of row sorting.

Please any one help me how to achive this scenario

Comment: Please show your code so we can help identify your problem :)

Comment: $('#shipmentEntryTable table thead').on('click', '.k-header .k-link', function () {$('#shipmentEntryTable tbody tr').each(function (e) { if ($(this).hasClass('.selected')) {                
                    $('#shipmentEntryTable tbody tr:eq(' + e + ')').addClass('selected');
                    $('#shipmentEntryTable tbody tr:eq(' + e + ')').find("td").eq(0).prepend("<div class='tableLinkBox'><p><span class='icon-checkmark'></span>Selected Rate and Carrier</p></div>");
                    $('.tableLinkBox').css('left', '0'); }});});

Comment: once i select the row then am displaying the div panel on selected row and the selected row has class called selected. when i click of sorting columns the selected row is refreshing means the class is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these posts, they are doing exactly what you need to do.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/keep-selection-on-page-change

http://www.telerik.com/forums/bug-grid-selection-dropping-on-sort

[kendo ui grid looses selection when bound value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845452/kendo-ui-grid-looses-selection-when-bound-value-changes)